# Using jQuery's FileInput library, how to find selected file name

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using http://plugins.jquery.com/fileinput/ to cover up the native browser file input button and text, so that I can have a custom image. The problem is that I can no longer get a hold of the filename once it's selected.

Does anyone either know how to do this or another way to customise a file input button as an image that will allow access to the filename?

To enable custom button (works well):

```
$('.contactform input[type=file]').fileinput('<img src="clip.png"/>');
```

Trying to access selected file name (result: ""):

```
$('.contactform input[type=file]').val().split('\\').pop();
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why, but when I try to find the value from within a jquery change event, it works. For example:

```
$("form input[type=file]").change(function() {
    $("form#jquery .filename").text( $(this).val().split('\\').pop() );
});
```

Here's my jsfiddle for anyone who's interested.

http://jsfiddle.net/w4jHs/